# Visual Basic 6 add backcolor to statusbar panel

Tags: vb6

I am fixing an old application which built on top of Visual Basic 6 code. There is an requirement that adding a statusbar on the bottom of the form. My status bar is as below:

[image]

I can show the text correctly but I also want to add a red background color. I found out there is no such option for StatusBar Panel. When I open the property of StatusBar, it shows as below:

[image]

I found out I can add picture. But When I added the red color picture, the text will be cover by the picture. I am stuck. Any advice will be helpful. Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I simply used the code from the link  @Étienne Laneville provided in the [comment](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13317). The background color added and also the text added.

Here is my code to call the function:

```
    PanelText StatusBar1, 9, "ATM (" & cntATM & ")", QBColor(12), QBColor(0)
```

But the text position is like below:

[image]

I have to make the text like below to position it, because this task was urgent for now and I have no time to investigate more.

```
    PanelText StatusBar1, 9, "ATM (" & cntATM & ")                           ", QBColor(12), QBColor(0)
```

Below is my output:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I tried the code provided by Brian M Stafford. But I got the same results. The text is still not at the center (Or to the Left). Below are my code and screenshot of status bar:

[image]

The function:

```
Private Sub PanelText(sb As StatusBar, pic As PictureBox, Index As Long, aText As String, bkColor As Long, _
    fgColor As Long, lAlign As Integer)

    Dim R As RECT

    SendMessage sb.hWnd, SB_GETRECT, Index - 1, R
    With pic
        Set .Font = sb.Font
        .Move 0, 0, (R.Right - R.Left + 2) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX, (R.Bottom - R.Top) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
        .BackColor = bkColor
        .Cls
        .ForeColor = fgColor
        .CurrentY = (.Height - .TextHeight(aText)) \ 2

        Select Case lAlign
            Case 0      ' Left Justified
                .CurrentX = 0
            Case 1      ' Right Justified
                .CurrentX = .Width - .TextWidth(aText) - Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 2
            Case 2      ' Centered
                .CurrentX = (.Width - .TextWidth(aText)) \ 2
        End Select

        pic.Print aText
        sb.Panels(Index).Text = aText
        sb.Panels(Index).Picture = .Image
    End With
End Sub
```

The API:

```
Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Const WM_USER = &H400
Private Const SB_GETRECT = (WM_USER + 10)

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib _
    "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As _
    Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As _
    Long, lParam As Any) As Long
```

Calling the function:

```
PanelText StatusBar1, picPanel, 9, "Test1", vbRed, vbBlack, 2

PanelText StatusBar1, picPanel, 10, "DFM (" & cntDFM & ")", vbRed, vbBlack, 2
```

I do not know why. May be I missed something or may be I set some property values to the StatusBar1 or picPanel(PictureBox).

**SOLUTION**

I set pictureBox, property AutoRedraw = True, and StatusBar, Panel, Alignment = sbrLeft. And everything works.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible natively. Take a look at this link: [Customize Colors and Fonts for Statusbar Panels](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13317), they _use a PictureBox control and an API call._

Comment: I've used the code from the link provided by @ÉtienneLaneville.  It works very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code [referenced in a comment](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13317) with some enhancements.  One enhancement is a parameter to specify text alignment:

```
Private Sub StatusBarPanelText(sb As StatusBar, pic As PictureBox, index As Long, aText As String, bkColor As Long, fgColor As Long, lAlign As Integer)
    Dim r As RECT

    SendMessage sb.hWnd, SB_GETRECT, index - 1, r

    With pic
        Set .Font = sb.Font
        .Move 0, 0, (r.Right - r.Left + 2) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX, (r.Bottom - r.Top) * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
        .BackColor = bkColor
        .Cls
        .ForeColor = fgColor
        .CurrentY = (.Height - .TextHeight(aText)) \ 2

        Select Case lAlign
            Case 0      ' Left Justified
                .CurrentX = 0
            Case 1      ' Right Justified
                .CurrentX = .Width - .TextWidth(aText) - Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 2
            Case 2      ' Centered
                .CurrentX = (.Width - .TextWidth(aText)) \ 2
        End Select

        pic.Print aText
        sb.Panels(index).Text = aText
        sb.Panels(index).Picture = .Image
    End With
End Sub
```

Here's the Windows API code:

```
    Private Type RECT
       Left As Long
       Top As Long
       Right As Long
       Bottom As Long
    End Type

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA"
       (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long,
        ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

    Private Const WM_USER = &H400
    Private Const SB_GETRECT = (WM_USER + 10)
```

The code is then used like this:

```
    Picture2.AutoRedraw = True
    Picture2.Visible = False

    StatusBarPanelText sbConfig, Picture2, 4, & _
       Format(Value / 1024, "#,###") & " KB", vbRed, vbWhite, 0
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you so much for the help. But I tried this code and it is still not working. Not sure why but the currentX property is not affecting the text position. And also I found out that event if I remove pic.Print aText, the text can still show.

Comment: @wadefanyaoxia I don't have any trouble with the code.  I notice my picturebox has 2 properties I had to change:  AutoRedraw = True and Visible = False.

Comment: WOW...I changed AutoRedraw = True. And It works. And also I have to change statusbar1 panel property Alignment to 0-sbrLeft. Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late arriving here and this particular issue may no longer matter, but here I am anyway. In trying to write a VB6 program for all versions of Windows from W-95 on, I ran into some color issues related to Microsoft's decision to change named color schemes for subsequent releases of Windows. What I have found is that using a virtual machine with Windows-98 and VB6 installed I can change the backgound color of status bars natively. That property is in the Properties box when using Win-98 but not XP and beyond. I guess the boys in Redmond wanted to enforce their look on our work and so removed that choice. I know this isn't a perfect solution, but it may be something you can live with.

Sorry, but this was my mistake. When I copied my files over from Win-7 to Win-98, VB6 replaced the status bar control with a picture box and named it statusbar1. I'm not sure why because the common controls option is checked and the status bar appears in the toolbox. Looks like the above solutions are the valid ones and mine isn't.